# Not able to upload file due to error "WebDriverError: Element is not reachable by keyboard" in Firefox browser

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor version 5.2.2. , geckodriver-v0.21.0 and Firefox browser version 61.When i am trying to run the protractor script in Firefox browser,it shows the error as

```
"WebDriverError:Element  <input id="logo" class="frx-input-file" name="logo" 
 type="file">is not reachable by keyboard.
   Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:
 32:19.891Z'
   System info: host: 'CS-COK-DEV-039', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 
'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
   Driver info: driver.version: unknown".
```

The protractor code is

```
var path = require('path');
var fileToUpload = "F://images/f2.jpg";
var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
element(by.css('.frx-form-section-container .frx-client-logo-field .frx-input-file')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

The UI code is

```
<div _ngcontent-c6="" class="frx-form-input-field-container frx-client-logo- 
field">
  <label _ngcontent-c6="" class="frx-input-file-label" for="logo">Upload 
  logo</label>
  <br _ngcontent-c6="">
  <span _ngcontent-c6="" class="frx-input-file-caption" for="logo">Will be 
   used on the templates and letters</span>
  <input _ngcontent-c6="" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .gif .JPG, .JPEG, .GIF, .BMP 
   ,.bmp" class="frx-input-file" id="logo" multiple="false" name="logo" 
   type="file">
</div>
```

The same protractor script is successfully running in both chrome and IE browser.How can we resolve this in Firefox.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Below code successfully worked for me in Firefox,Chrome and IE.

```
var path = require('path');
//use your file's path
var fileToUpload = "../files/helthplan.png";
var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
//use your application's locator for upload input file.
var fileElem = element(by.css(".frx-form-section-container .frx-client-logo-field .frx- input-file"));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'inline';", 
fileElem.getWebElement());
element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

directConnect: false,

{ browserName: 'firefox', 'moz:webdriverClick': false }

set these properties enter code herein your configuration file that will resolve the issue.